# How do I make tag i WCAG 2.0 compatible?

Tags: validation, icons, semantic-ui, wcag2.0, italic

I'm using Semantic-UI framework and for the icons I have to use the `i` tag. Here is an example:

```
<i class="icon search"></i>
```

I want to make my code compliant to WCAG 2.0 (level AA) and I'm using [AChecker validator](http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php). For every line that contains `i` tag I get the following error:

```
1.4 Distinguishable: Make it easier for users to see and hear content including separating foreground from background.

Success Criteria 1.4.4 Resize text (AA)

Check 117: i (italic) element used.
Repair: Replace your i elements with em or strong.
```

Since I can't replace it with `em` or `strong` because of the Semantic-UI components usage and because I'm not using `i` for *italic*, do you know how can I fix it or any work-around to get no errors by checker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Font Awesome WCAG 2.0 compatible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015537/how-do-i-make-font-awesome-wcag-2-0-compatible)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In that question the solution is to use `span` that works with Font Awesome. I'm not using FA, as I write in my question I'm using Semantic-UI.

Comment: how do i make this work in wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are tying yourself into 'Semantic-UI' as your framework of choice, as I see it you have two options:

1. Change the source `icons.css` component and swap out `i.icon`
   references for `span.icon` then use a `<span>` element.
2. Actually address the accessibility issue, instead of trying to work around it. Judging by the icon you are using `<i class="icon search"></i>` looks like users of assistive technologies would need an alternate description.

Font Awesome have some pretty good advice:

> **Icons with semantic or interactive purpose**
>
> If you're using an icon to convey meaning (rather than only as a decorative element), ensure that this meaning is also conveyed to assistive technologies. This goes for content you're abbreviating via icons as well as interactive controls (buttons, form elements, toggles, etc.).
>
> http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/

Comment: The option 2 doesn't work: achecker doens't validate it. Besides, FA accessibility seems not to be compliant with WGAG 2.0, since achecker keeps returning errors.

Comment: Well your issue is with the framework and its choice of icon font implementation.