# <i> is not compatible with WCAG standards?

Tags: font-awesome, wcag2.0

So I'm working on updating the WCAG 2.0 accessibility of a site that uses Font Awesome icons. The issue is that the guidelines state that italics shouldn't be used. I know that using FA isn't actually italics, but when you do a code check, it comes up with a warning and I'm trying to limit any warnings, even if they are not a real issue.
Does anyone have a good workaround for this?

Here's what the documentation says about italics: https://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=117

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Font Awesome WCAG 2.0 compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015537/how-do-i-make-font-awesome-wcag-2-0-compatible)

Comment: how do i do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Use  tag instead. Both the  and  elements are widely used for icons. You can read more in here: [Should I use <i> tag for icons instead of <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135261/should-i-use-i-tag-for-icons-instead-of-span)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there's anything in [WCAG 2.0 Guideline 1.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast.html) that actually prohibits the usage of the `<i>` element.

A more relevant consideration would be to ask whether non-sighted users will understand the intent of your font-awesome glyphs. Just because something is *compliant* doesn't mean that it's actually *useful* to humans.

I recommend reviewing the [Font Awesome Techniques for Accessibility](http://fontawesome.io/accessibility/), since it doesn't look like you're currently implementing them.

The two accessibility arguments for not using the `<i>` element are:

1. Screen readers may not announce the change from regular to italicized text, since `<i>` is a presentational element, rather than a semantic element like `<em>`
2. Large blocks of italicized text may be more difficult to read for persons with dyslexia

Since neither of these really apply to your situation, I would ignore this error.

Comment: how do i do this in wordpress?

Comment: Use basic HTML rather than shortcodes. Then you have total control of the code.